# Compactar Arquivos em PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Como posso criar um script em PowerShell para compactar os arquivos de uma pasta especifica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando [**`Compress-Archive`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Compress-Archive C:\Origem -DestinationPath ('C:\Destino\arquivo.zip')
```

Ou usando a classe [**`ZipFile`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.zipfile) do .NET Framework

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("C:\Origem", "C:\Destino\arquivo.zip")
```

[Adicionei os dois scripts no GitHub para referência futura.](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/PowerShell/270398)